# url value and iframe in a view

Tags: playframework

IDE: netbeans
Playframework: v 1.2.4

from my app/controllers/application.java i call following

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
   render("Application/Showresult.html");
}
```

when i look at the URL it states localhost/application/process

and i can see the result.

Why does it show that URL?

In one of my views i have an iframe. The src of iframe is pointed to a html file which the graphic team can drop in view folder after deploying to production.

Do i have to place the html file which will be given post production to views folder and call it as such from the iframe

myview.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="click" title="click me" ></button>
        <iframe src="@{'graphicteamview.html'}">
    </body>
</html>
```

or do i have to tell graphic team to drop their html in public folder and then access it as such

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="click" title="click me" ></button>
        <iframe src="@{'public/iframeHTML/somepage.html'}">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a static resource, store it under Public folder.